# Discrete distributions such that $P(XY=ab) = P(X=a)P(Y=b)$

Tags: probability, arithmetic, multiplicative-function

I invented a fun exercise:

Suppose X and Y are discrete **independent** random variables over $\mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\forall a, b \in \mathbb{N}, ~~\mathbb{P}(X*Y = a*b) = \mathbb{P}(X=a) *\mathbb{P}(Y=b)$$

It is possible to show that $X = Y = 1$.

Now, I'm trying to see whether this holds if I **remove the independence assumption**.

One can show:

- $f(x) := \mathbb{P}(X=x) = \mathbb{P}(Y=x)$
- $f(1) \neq 0$
- $g(x) := \frac{f(x)}{f(1)}$ is [completely multiplicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_multiplicative_function)
- $0 < \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} g(i) = \prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}} \frac1{1-g(p)}= \frac1{f(1)} < \infty$

I didn't find nice properties on the joint distribution $\mathbb{P}(X=x \land Y=y)$.

Can you find examples other than  $X=Y=1$ or prove they don't exist?

EDIT: thank you @Thomas Andrews for pointing out we need $X,Y \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Your first conclusion (assuming independence) is not correct. Take X to be 1 or 2 with equal probability and Y to be 3 or 4 with equal probability.

Comment: More generally any independent random variables supported by two sets A and B such that any element of AB has a unique décomposition in the form ab (a in A and b in B) will do

Comment: @Olivier Your example does not work because $P(X\cdot Y = 3 \cdot 2) \neq P(X=3)P(Y=2)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews you are right, thank you

Comment: Oupssss. Good point !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only such random variables are still identically 1.

We have, 
\begin{align}
1 &=\sum_{a \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{P}(X\cdot Y=a \cdot 1)\\
&=\sum_{a \in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{P}(X=a)\mathbb{P}(Y=1)\\
&=\mathbb{P}(Y=1).
\end{align}
Similarly, switching the roles of $X$ and $Y$,
\begin{align*}
1&=\sum_{a \in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{P}(X\cdot Y = 1\cdot a)\\
&=\sum_{a \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{P}(X=1)\mathbb{P}(Y=a)\\
&= \mathbb{P}(X=1).
\end{align*}

This is assuming Thomas Andrew's point that you must restrict $a$ and $b$ to be in $\mathbb{N}$, not $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Small nitpick. This shows that $X=1$ a.s. It is still possible that $X=2$ on a non-empty set with probability $0$.

Comment: Nice solution, thanks @kccu !